# Restricting the ordering of a given permutation

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $p_1p_2p_3...p_n$ be a randomly-selected n-permutation.

Why is $P(p_1>p_2>p_3)=\frac 16$?

(P denotes probability.)

Comment: In how many ways can a triple of distinct numbers be arranged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $n!$ ways to arrange $n$ distinct numbers. The condition $p_1 > p_2 > \dotsc > p_n$ singles out one of these ways. If all permutations are equally probable, each then has a probability of $\frac{1}{n!}$.